# debugging AFNetworking memory usage spikes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

I have a UICollectionViewCell, in which it has a UIImageView abd I am using the AFNetworking UIImageView category to help me load the images. I've profiled my app and it seems that the memory spike is over the top, it just keeps increasing and increasing after profiling it via Instruments under allocation tools.

[image]

I am not sure what happened here and how to fix this. Cells are being reused all the time, but it's just that maybe these images aren't purged from the cache or something. Here's some code of how I am using it, it's pretty straightforward:

```
  NSURLRequest *imageURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];

  [self.imageView_ setImageWithURLRequest:imageURLRequest placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        weakSelf.imageView_.image = image;
        weakSelf.imageView_.alpha = 0.0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            weakSelf.imageView_.alpha = 1.0;
        }];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

If I remove this code to download the image, then the memory footprint is way smaller. Any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: you might consider streaming directly to flash storage...

Comment: what does that even mean?\

Comment: it means instead of allocating memory (RAM) to hold the downloaded images, open a file on "disk" and append any received content to that file. You won't use as much RAM.

Comment: although I see you are just using NSURLConnection to automatically do the download--maybe there's an option to have it download to a file instead.

Comment: what's in `-setImageWithURLRequest`?

Comment: @nielsbot it's AFNetworking

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it in [autoreleasepool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) and check your memory usage

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Code that creates autoreleased objects.
}
```

Comment: (in your async callback/received data processing loop)